# How to install wordcloud in python3.6?

Tags: python-3.6, word-cloud

I installed wordcloud via conda in Windows 64

```
conda install -c conda-forge word cloud
```

but that is python 3.4.

I want to install word cloud in python 3.6
but i did search the google. 
 but it is not effect. so please teach me....

Answer (score 4):

Anaconda Python 3.6 version
For Windows

==== Installation of wordcloud package ====

1. download wordcloud‑1.3.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud
2. Copy the file to your current working directory
3. Open command prompt from Tools
4. python -m pip install wordcloud-1.3.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

It should work now

For MAC

pip install wordcloud

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, you can download a third party package for Python 3. Following the below steps helped me solve the problem.

[Wordcloud_successful_install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak4mg.png)

1. Download wordcloud‑1.3.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud
2. Copy the file to your current working directory
3. Open command prompt from Tools
4. Python -m pip install wordcloud-1.3.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 1):

This will work:
 
 1. create virEnv: conda create -n yourenvname python=3.5 anaconda
 
 2. source activate yourenvname
 
 3. conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud

Answer (score 0):

1. Install wordcloud from the following page:
   https://pypi.org/project/wordcloud/
2. Note: command: `pip install wordcloud`
3. Note: run the above command in Anaconda cmd prompt
4. Pre-requisities for instaling wordcloud is to install Visual C++(I got this error to install. So, you may give a try).This requires almost 4GB space. Once installed, restart your machine and then try the 1st step. It should be successful this time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved my issue using wheels. Here are the steps:

Download the .whl file compatible with your Python version and your windows distribution (32bit or 64bit) from here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud
cd to the file path
Run this command python -m pip install